# Twitter Timeline through Expression Engine

Tags: twitter, expressionengine

Can anyone help me integrate Twitter through Expression Engine. I am new to expression engine and I have tried to follow the example the **[Twitter Timeline](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/twitter_timeline/)** developed by the EE team but couldn't get it working.

Can anyone help me with step by step process in EE2?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post the exact code you're using if you want some help here I'm afraid. Though since Twitter Timeline is a "first party" plugin (developed by EllisLab themselves), you should just post your questions in the [technical support forum](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/105/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example from the [Twitter Timeline Plugin](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/twitter_timeline/) download page, insert the following code into one of your ExpressionEngine templates:

```
{exp:twitter_timeline screen_name="ladygaga" limit="3"}
    <div class="tweet">
        <div class="date">{created_at format="%m-%d %g:%i"}</div>
        <div class="author">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="{profile_image_url}" width="48" height="48" alt="" />
            </div>
            {name}
        </div>
        <div class="status">{text}</div>
    </div>
{/exp:twitter_timeline}
```

Note: The plugin only works on public Twitter feeds, so make sure that the feed your trying to display **is not private**. For this example, I'm using [Lady Gaga's twitter stream](http://twitter.com/ladygaga).

All error messages are logged in the Template Parsing Log.

Therefore if you have no output, or unexpected output, enable the Template Parsing Log in the Control Panel's [Output and Debugging Preferences](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/system_admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html) at: **CP Home > Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging**.

[image]

Reload the page in your browser and look through the Template Parsing Log for information from the Twitter Timeline:

[image]

If you still can't get the Twitter Timeline plugin to work, post a description of your problem to the [ExpressionEngine 2 Technical Support Forum](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/105/) — they'll be able to better help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the reply. I tried what you said and this the error which I am getting.. I think I am making some dumb mistake!

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 1034

Error

The following tag has a syntax error:

{exp:twitter_timeline}

Please correct the syntax in your template.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have installed? You can [find out](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/tools/utilities/php_info.html) by going to CP Home > Tools > Utilities > PHP Info. Do you get the error if you create a blank, new template and paste in the example code and nothing else?

Comment: its php5.2.. and i ma pasting the example in the file on which I have worked before, its not an empty template.